# How do I include JQuery and Bootstrap.min.js in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

This has been asked before but I am still struggling with understanding it.

I have wp_head() in my header.php file in the `<HEAD> </HEAD>`.

In my functions.php I have:

```
    <?php

function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/bootstrap.min.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );

?>
```

In js/ I have bootstrap.min.js and jquery-1.11.0.min.js.

The reason I know it isn't working is because I have a carousel in bootstrap which isn't running, as it requires bootstrap.min.js.

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

You need a '/' before 'js', like

```
get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js',
```

get_stylesheet_directory_uri() is the same way. These functions return a uri *without* a trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

Your js is loaded correctly. You should just make sure that it is in the js folder. Another point to take note of, if you are using a child theme, you should use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`. For more info refer to the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)